# What kind of map is this

Tags: qgis

I would like to have/create a map of Kazakhstan in the same way as in the attached picture (grey map of UK and Ireland) using QGIS? I don't know what kind of map is this, what its name and where I can get it? And how to have it in this small size with a point on it?

[image: Grey map]

Comment: What kind of map? A grey one with a dot on it.

Comment: Sasha, if you are new to all things GIS - people might be a little less harsh if you declare that, but in general you will get a better response if you are more specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would call that an "inset map" (that is, inset to another image or even map).  I use them a lot to give a quick visual context to a higher resolution map on the same page.

There are quite a few sources of basic country outline data such as [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/), [SLAB](http://www.unsalb.org/) and [World Borders Dataset](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php) from which you should be able to make a suitable simple inset map for Kazakhstan.  Open the data in QGIS, select Kazakhstan from the layer's attributes and zoom to the location.  Use a point dataset to place your point or add a point manually in the Map Composer and/or add labels to suit.  You can then export your map as an image file from the Map Composer.  If you already have the image you want to add the inset map to, you could include that in yuour map composition in QGIS.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a political map to me (just country outlines).  If I was going to make a map like the one in your photo, I would start with data from Natural Earth Data http://www.naturalearthdata.com Then you can select the countries you are interested in to make a new data layer and digitize a point where you want it.